# Zelen Exact Test - Trying to use a k 2x2 in the function zelen.test()

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `zelen.test` function on the package NSM3. I am having difficulty reading the data into the function.

You can recreate my data using

```
data <- c(4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1, 12, 13,
            74, 74, 77, 85, 31, 37, 11, 7, 18, 18, 96, 97, 48, 40)
events <- matrix(data, ncol = 2)
```

The documentation on CRAN states that `zelen.test(z, example = F, r = 3)` where `z` is an array of k 2 x 2 matrix, example is set to `FALSE` because it returns a p-value for an example I cannot access, and r is the number of decimals the users wants returned in the p-value.

I've tried:

```
zelen.test(events, r = 4)
```

I thought it may want the study number and the trial data, so I tried this:

```
studies <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7)
data <- c(4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1, 12, 13,
            74, 74, 77, 85, 31, 37, 11, 7, 18, 18, 96, 97, 48, 40)
events <- matrix(cbind(studies, events), ncol = 3)
zelen.test(events, r = 4)
```

but it continues to return and error stating

> "Error in z[1, 1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions" for both cases I tried above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the source code by typing `zelen.test` on the console, if the `example = TRUE`, it is constructing a `3D` array

```
...
   if (example) 
      z <- array(c(2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 1), dim = c(2, 2, 2))

...
```

The input `z` `dim` is also specified in the documentation of `?zelen.test`

> z - data as an array of k 2x2 matrices. Small data sets only!

So, we may need to construct an `array` of dimensions 3

```
library(NSM3)
z1 <- array(c(4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 3, 4, 7), c(2, 2, 2))
zelen.test(z1, r = 4)

# Zelen's test: 
# P = 1
```

Or with 3rd dimension of length 3

```
z1 <- array( c(4, 2, 3, 3, 8, 3, 4, 7, 0, 7, 1, 1), c(2, 2, 3))
zelen.test(z1, r = 4)

# Zelen's test:
#P = 0.1238
```